# Distributing the XML files

Tags: java, xml

I am totally new to XML and its capabilities.

I have a file say `xyz.xml`. 
It contains content like this:

```
<system-config>
    <business-model>
      <agent-category key="operator">
         <singular-name>Operator</singular-name>
         <plural-name>Operators</plural-name>
         <attribute>agent-attribute.reference</attribute>
      </agent-category>
```

Next I have

```
  <agent-attribute id="agent-attribute.reference">
     <name>Reference</name>
     < description>A unique identifier for this agent, typically an MSISDN.</description>
     <mandatory>true< /mandatory>
     <editable>false< /editable>
     <deletable>false< /deletable>
     <sensitive>false< /sensitive>
     <system-generated>false< /system-generated>
     <input-method xsi:type="AgentReferenceInputMethod"></input-method>
     <storage-location xsi:type="AgentRefStorage" field="reference"></storage-location>
     </agent-attribute>
 </business-model>
```

Now I want to distribute the agent-attributes to different file named agentAttr.xml.

Is it possible to do so (mind it `<agent-attribute>` is under `<system-config><business-model>`), if so how?

Comment: parse the xml files and create a new one with those attributes? I'm not sure i understand the problem.

Comment: Its based on the Schema of System-Config XML and the application which will be consuming this XML. If it demands the presence of `agent-attribute` in the same file; you can't distribute it.

Comment: Ok so it means there is no other way else then to code it so. This means that XML itself doesn't provide any such facility. Thanks for the replies that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to extract the agent-attribute portions ?. You can do that with simple XSLT transformation (use e.g. [Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) for that). Another option could be [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), parsing it using DOM or manually.